# Is schema’s backward & forward compatibility better than optional fields?

Tags: protocol-buffers, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

I’m using JsonSchema and I wonder what’s the need for technologies like Confluent Schema Registry, since their “killer feature” (other than version control which I can achieve in Git), is the backward & forward compatibility.

I’d like to know why is this feature worth something, when I can easily add / remove fields anywhere in a micro services architecture as long as they’re optional (the same applies to Protobuf). If so, then what’s the use case for backward & forward compatibility?

Comment: Regardless of compatibility, can your Kafka clients use Git, for example, to actually download and register schemas? That's the main feature - is that there is a well-defined API contract for actually using the data (for Kafka, and externally)

Comment: You may also be interested in https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/1242

Comment: I can easily wrap git with an API. And in the code I’ll need to define a POJO anyway so I don’t get this feature too

Comment: Your code doesn't need to define its own POJO, though. They can be generated from a schema that would be downloaded before your code compiles. Or you can publish generated POJO as a regular, external maven dependency

Comment: Does Confluent Schema Registry help me with this? Assuming I generate a POJO from JsonSchema, I'll need to build on each change. What's Confluent Schema Registry's job here?